# Lipschitz condition proof

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, banach-fixed-point

Trying for find the Lipschitz constant for $f(x) = \frac{1-x^5}{7}$ on $[0,1]$

I get to:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| = \frac{1}{7}|x^5-y^5|$$

But I cannot see a way to proceed further to get to $\dots \leq K |x-y|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x>y$. By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem),
$$
\frac{x^5-y^5}{x-y}=5c^4
$$
for some $c\in(y,x)$. Hence,
$$
|x^5-y^5|=5c^4|x-y|\le5|x-y|.
$$

Comment: I think $c\in(x,y)$ would be better, no? Because $x,y$ are not constant. You then take the maximum of all possible $c$ which is $1$ and get a condition that always holds.

Comment: @DaBamti You're absolutely right. I will correct my answer.